# Multiple awk print in single command

Tags: awk

Here are the 2 command which we need to execute, there are two ways to execute this in one line either by `;` or `|`. Is there any other way to execute it via `awk` command.

These are the below command which is getting executed twice, is it possible to have one command with multiple `awk print` as shown in the example command tried.

```
isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "\t\t\tSnapshot USED %=%.1f%%\n", $4}'
     Snapshot USED =0.6%
isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "\t\t\tSnapshot USED:" $1}'
     Snapshot USED=3.2T
```

**Example command tried:**

```
isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "\t\t\tSnapshot USED %:%.1f%%\n", $4}'; awk '{ print "\t\t\tSnapshot USED:" $1}'

Snapshot USED =0.6%
Snapshot USED=3.2T
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the output of the two awk statements next to each other on one line. Since you are giving different input to awk each time, how about first storing the results of each line in a separate variable and then print out both variables next to each other?

Comment: use one `awk` statement with one `printf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use one-line command to do it,

```
isi_classic snapshot usage | awk -v OFS='\t\t\t' 'END{printf "%sSnapshot USED %=%.1f%%\n%sSnapshot USED:%s\n",OFS,$4,OFS,$1}'
```

Brief explanation,

- No need to use `tail`, `awk 'END{}'` can do the same thing
- You can combine your `printf` and `print` command to one
- It would be better to substitute the `'\t\t\t'` as `OFS` to make the command more readable

Comment: That will only produce the output you want in some awks since the value of fields in the END section is undefined by POSIX.